# Backup an entire VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to back up my entire system, with all programs and files that are currently installed on the VM. How can I do this?

If I lose my computer or something goes wrong with my operating system, I would like to have this security backup.

Answer (score 7):

To backup a full VM in VirtualBox we only need to save your virtual hard drive that has the `.vdi` extension.

On Linux, the HD is usually in:

`user_name/.VirtualBox/HardDisks/harddisk_name.vdi`

Just copy this file and save it in some safe place.

To restore the backup, just select the `.vdi` file as the image's HD when creating a VM in VirtualBox.

Comment: +1 export command is really slow and unpractical when needing to backup large vms, yet everyone seems to be using it.

Comment: Thanks. but will this recreate the MAC address of the network card attached to the VM?

Comment: As far as I know, Linux systems save this type of information in the file system.

Answer (score 6):

Export the VM...

```
vboxmanage export vmname -o vmname.ova
```

...and import...

```
vboxmanage import vmname
```

Comment: This method isn't practical for larger vms. It takes long to export. Instead one should just copy the VDI file as @Thiago Krempser pointed out.

Comment: I presume that exporting can happen while the VM is running, while copying the VDI can only be done while the VM is off?